# Mutating arrays state while still in build mode

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Say I have an array :

```
 This.state = {
    People: [
      {name: ‘Bec’, age: 23, state: ‘qld’},
      {name: ‘Corey ’, age: 23, state: ‘nsw’},
      {name: ‘Karen ’, age: 23, state: ‘qld’},
 ]
}
```

I want to be able to add thousands of objects to the array with ease while still in build mode. Without having to type all of the props individually every time.

My idea is to have a form that I use while in npm start. With fields for name, age and state etc. And when I submit the form it mutates the state of my array so that the new object  is physically in my array in my text editor. I would use this form only in build mode the then remove it from the render before running npm build.

I know that they say don’t mutate state but does that still matter while in build mode ? I just want a fast and clean way to add to an array without having to type it all every time as I’m looking at having thousands and thousands of objects.

I’m open to any other ideas but for now this seems like it would be the most efficient way. I’m struggling to find any information on this.

Comment: If it's static data, why not create a `.json` file and import it where you need it?

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate I’m a beginner. I thought the best way would just to be have input fields. Where I can just type props in and onSubmit it just push the new object into the arrays state. But I can’t find anything to help me with this.

Comment: Well how can you have a form if your app hasn't started? If you need to get a lot of 'start-up' data in to your app (and it's won't change often), then you can just create a static .json file in your project and import or require it. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

Comment: Well because I can run npm start and use the form to add to the arrays before using localhost. Then before running npm build and deploying remove the form from the render. So that it’s not available other users.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what those two commands do... npm start builds your app in a virtual dev server and runs it. If you then stop it, any data you enter will disappear. npm build just builds the package into your local file system. They're separate.

Comment: So a form cannot mutate the original state of the array. ? ?

Comment: Could you explain how you would add to an arrays state. Efficiently. Keeping in mind I want it to be there in the original state so that I can find it and easily remove it if I wish.

Comment: So... you want a random value generator ? Make a file containing everything then loading it ? How do you want to remove stuff ?

Comment: So at the moment I have an array similar to above. All I want is a way to add thousands of objects With various Props to it. While still in build mode. I thought maybe I could make a form that I use in local host to push and mutate the arrays state. And then remove the form before deploying the site to public. Clearly I’m on the complete wrong track.